# Example using attr()

Tags: javascript, attr

Following this question - [Extending Clone Table Rows functionality - changing row ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985899/extending-clone-table-rows-functionality-changing-row-id)

The code - http://jsfiddle.net/EwQUW/58/

I want to update the attr. Please check the code and I have included comments to see what I am talking about.

**EDIT**

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="make[]" id="make" onchange="change(this,'model')">
                    <option value="" selected=“selected”> Please Select </option>
                    <option value=Ford> Ford</option>
                    <option value=Nissan> Nissan</option>
                    <option value=Volvo> Volvo</option>
                    <option value=BMW> BMW</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <select name="model[]" id="model" onchange="change(this,'make')">
                    <option value="" selected=“selected”> Please Select </option>
                    <option value=Ford> Fiesta</option>
                    <option value=Nissan> Mirca</option>
                    <option value=Volvo> s60</option>
                    <option value=BMW> M3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="country" name="country[]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="city" name="city[]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Javascript

```
function change(fld,id) {
    var opt = fld.selectedIndex;
    if (fld[opt].value != ' ') {
        var sel = document.getElementById(id);
        for (var i = sel.options.length -1; i > -1; i--) {
            if (fld[opt].value == sel[i].value) sel[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I add a new row, I want the ID, NAME and onchange to be updated with a count or length as you put.

As ID are updated and onchange to id=make to id=make2 so the onchange still works

**EDIT AGAIN**

Actually names will be an array. So only IDS and Onchange needs updating depending on number of rows

Comment: May I offer a less complex method: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ef3eg/1/).

Comment: does this change the id when the rows are cloned? Could I add find("input,select") in?

Comment: Yes. If you're using a web browser with a JavaScript console (Chrome/Chromium/Safari have Web Inspector, Opera has Dragonfly, Firefox has Firebug, IE has...something?), you should be able to right-click the cloned rows/elements and select 'inspect element.' This will show the element in the DOM. I did however forget to update the demo link to a working version: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ef3eg/2/).

Comment: one of the attributes I got in the dropdown list is onchange="change(this,'country')". How can I add length onto it? where I want the onchange="change(this,'country2')"

Comment: You're using jQuery: stop using in-line JavaScript. ...I posted this as a demo, would you like me to post an actual answer?

Comment: Please post your actual (relevant) starting html, and state any criteria you have by which you'd judge an answer to be 'successful.'

Comment: I have up changed my question and insert my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first means I've come up with is:

```
function change(fld, id) {
    var opt = fld.selectedIndex;
    if (fld[opt].value != ' ') {
        var sel = document.getElementById(id);
        for (var i = sel.options.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            if (fld[opt].value == sel[i].value) sel[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}

$('select').change( // moving away from intrusive in-line JavaScript
    function() {
        var changeTarget; // used to determine which select to change
        if (this.id == 'make') {
            changeTarget = 'model';
        }
        else {
            changeTarget = 'make';
        }
        change(this,changeTarget);
    });

$('#add').click(

function() {
    $('#table tbody tr:last').clone(true).appendTo($('#table')).find('input,select').each(

    function() {
        var attr = this.id.replace(/\d/, ''); // gets the text of the id attribute
        var length = $('#table tbody tr').length; // finds what number the new attributes should be
        if ($(this).is('input')){ // select elements don't need their name to be changed
            $(this).attr({
                'id': attr + length,
                'name': attr + length
            });
        }
        else if ($(this).is('select')){
            $(this).attr('id',attr + length);
        }

    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ef3eg/3/).

---

**Edited** to remove the hard-coded 'make'/'model' choice in the `select` `change()` event-handler to the following:

```
$('select').change(
    function() {
        var changeTarget = $(this)
            .closest('tr')
            .find($('select'))
            .not($(this))
            .attr('id');
        change(this,changeTarget);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ef3eg/4/).

Comment: The fiddle provided doesnt seem to be correct. When new row is added, the new row Make controls the Make in the row above. Where as Model controls the Make in the above row not the one in the same row

Comment: As you said moving away from in-line javascript, is it possible in juuery to link it?

Comment: Works a treat! One last thing, do you know how to validate a textfield which is .show() and not validate if .hide(). As I will include into my system at a later date, so if I select BMW, a textfield will appear in the same <td></td> of the dropdown list state Year of Car depending in which row I selected it

Comment: Is it possible to link what? I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. To your immediately-previous comment, yes: but I'm afraid I need to go to bed, now. I'll try to remember to look tomorrow night, after work though.

Comment: You need to add to your question what you mean by 'validate.' Explain, step-by-step, what you expect to happen.