# jQuery remove cloned element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that removes the duplicated form when clicked. But when you hit remove I want to only remove the form the was cloned. I believe i need to use `$this` but not sure how?

**jQuery**

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    $('.duplicate').remove();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="duplicate">
    <p>Form Duplicate</p>
    <a href="#" class="add">Add Guest</a> | <a href="#" class="remove">Remove </a>
</div>
<div class="duplicate">
    <p>Form Duplicate</p>
    <a href="#" class="add">Add Guest</a> | <a href="#" class="remove">Remove </a>
</div>
```

Here's a live preview: http://www.waterfrontexeter.co.uk/preordernew/.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's my answer for 
[remove clone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985899/extending-clone-table-rows-functionality-changing-row-id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and don't forget about [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$(".remove").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".duplicate").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Also don't forget that you will need to re-bind the click every time a new duplicate is added. This can get expensive if you keep your selector as $(".remove") so you should change that to be scoped to whatever you created.

Comment: I had added this code above to the live preview but this is not working any ideas?

Comment: @awbergs It depends on how cloning is done. It is possible to preserve bound events.

Comment: Any ideas how I can get this to work? Maybe awbergs was right when i need to rebind click.

Comment: All I'm saying is that it seems like the item could be cloned after the **$(".remove").click** call. Events for the existing items would be preserved but doing a selector by class name only is costly so I like to point it out every time I see it :)

Comment: @BrentFrench If you have `click` event fired, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw8z4/.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark correct as this works but, im really baffled why it does not work when the item is cloned :S

Comment: This is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw8z4/2/

Every time you clone an item you need to bind the remove event

Comment: @awbergs I guess you don't know how to clone items with jQuery `:)`. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw8z4/1/.